# Recent GPS III Launch Intended or Unplanned Venting?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, engine-design

Between 14:01 and 14:14 in the following video, there is a significant gas vent happening behind the engine bell:

Is this working as intended, or does that appear to be a blown gasket or other leak?